# An anime where the main character lives with a bunch of "outcasts" and has to take care of a girl without any social skills

Tags: the-pet-girl-of-sakurasou

I was watching it by the Japanese name and lost it.

The main character goes to a college that is divided between the art section and all the others. He lives on a house where the "outcasts" stay. I remember he was put there because he refused to leave some kittens he found on the street, but he couldn't stay on the main dorm if he kept them.

He lives with one guy that is that harem main character type who gets all the girls he wants all the time, one girl that is always teasing the main character although she's actually into this other guy that I mentioned. There's also a guy who never leaves his room and only communicates with the others by an avatar called Maid.

And there's also this female teacher whose niece (if I'm not mistaken, it's her relative of some sort) comes to this art college and stays on the house with them. She's slow as hell and doesn't really have any social skills (but it's not that she can't relate to other people). For example, when she wants to eat something from a store, she just gets it and eats it without paying for it because she just doesn't realize she can't do that). However, at the same time, she's a world famous painter and now she's trying to become a mangaka. Her name is Sora, and she resembles Sora from No Game No Life but older with the body closer to a woman than a little girl like this other Sora. And the main character is the one who takes care of her.

The main character also has this friend whose parents don't give her the proper support to pursue her dream of studying art, so she has to live by her own means. She works so hard and doesn't accept help from others so she passes out more than once. She eventually end up living in the house with them so that she could stop spending money on rent.

I guess that's all I remember. If I wasn't clear about something or if you want to ask some questions to help me remember, feel free to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds just like [**Sakurasou no Pet na Kanojo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pet_Girl_of_Sakurasou) (The Pet Girl of Sakurasou).

Some points that matches your description:

- They all attend Suimei University of the Arts, which is divided into 2 divisions: Arts Division and Regular Division.
- They all live in Sakurasou, where they do not fit in any other dorms because they are unique.
- The main character, Sorata, had to take care of Shiina as the latter is incapable of doing anything by herself. She is a world renowned painter and is working to be a mangaka.
- Nanami later moves to Sakurasou because she couldn't afford her rent. Her dream is to be a **seiyuu**, but her family opposes her decision and doesn't provide any support, so she had to word part-time for expenses.
- There is an avatar called Maid-chan, an A.I developed by the hikikomori Ryuunosuke.

There are of course some things that doesn't match your description, but it might have been a mistake.

Comment: Damn, I was just thinking of that one aswell. :D

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot! And yes, some things I just coudn't remember quite well but I wanted to put as much information as I could anyway. It's Shiina. I had Sora on my mind because the first thing that caught my attention on her was that they look alike at least I think so.

Comment: But it's actually Shiro and not Sora anyway (I am really bad with characters names).

Comment: You got confused by the names, which is completely understandable IMHO since I get confused about them too :) The reason being their names actually overlap: (SnPnK) **Sora**ta & Ma**shiro**; **Sora** and **Shiro** (NGNL). And aside from the slight similarities in appearance, the two pairs are actually voiced by the SAME seiyuu: [Yoshitsugu Matsuoka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshitsugu_Matsuoka) and [Ai Kayano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ai_Kayano). IIRC, they were directed by the same person and although done by different studios, there are little yet noticeable art style similarities :)